# FancyBox opens outside of browser/screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, positioning

I'm working on a page in which I'll have a few different groups of images that I'd like to open for a user when they click on the thumbnail, and do so in FancyBox.

I more or less have it working, but there's a major problem - all the images (1680x1050, PNGs) open at an off-screen position as though their top and left values were set in relation to the screen itself to -80% and 75%, respectively.

Translation: I only see the bottom-left quarter (at most) of the image when it opens.

I've done a good deal of searching with Google, SO, GitHub (the FB project's source), et cetera, and have yet to find a solution, or even anyone experiencing the same problem.

I'm probably missing something obvious, or at least obvious to seasoned veterans, but I'm a bit new and a bit tired. Anyone have any ideas?

On JFK's advice, I've put what I believe to be all the relevant code into a jsfiddle (something I had heard of, but never before even seen, let alone used). It can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ericb222/ttvpg8vp/4/

Also, the jQuery I'm using is:

```
jquery 2.1.1
jQueryui 1.11.2
```

Please, feel free to let me know if you need more of the code. I'm new to programming; I've only just completed a two-year degree that focused on Java and SQL.

```
/* HTML */

<div id="content">
    <div id="content_body">
        <div id="content_left">
        </div><!--Close of content_left-->
        <div id="content_right">
            <div id="oms" class="content_block_standard">
                <div class="screenshots">

                    <a href="http://www.ejbdev.com/academia/oms/1_Portal.png" class="fancybox fancybox.image" rel="oms_gallery" title="Text"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://www.ejbdev.com/academia/oms/1_Portal.png" /></a>

                    <a href="http://www.ejbdev.com/academia/oms/2_Roster.png" class="fancybox fancybox.image" rel="oms_gallery" title="Text"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://www.ejbdev.com/academia/oms/2_Roster.png" /></a>

                    <a href="http://www.ejbdev.com/academia/oms/3_Add.png" class="fancybox fancybox.image" rel="oms_gallery" title="Text"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://www.ejbdev.com/academia/oms/3_Add.png" /></a>

                </div><!-- /screenshots -->
            </div><!-- /content_block_standard for OMS project -->
        </div><!-- /#content_right -->
    </div><!-- /#content_body -->
</div><!-- /#content -->

/* Javascript (from <head>) */

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'elastic'
    });
});

/* CSS */

div#content {
    /* Positioning */
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
    position:           relative;
    top:                4.0em;
    margin-bottom:      16px;
    /* Sizing */
    width:              960px;
    /* Styling */
    border-top:         none;
}
    div#content_body {
        margin:         0;
        padding:        0;
        display:        table;
        position:       relative;
        top:            0px;
        left:           0px;
        height:         100%;
    }
    div#content_left {
        width:          192px;
        height:         100%;
        margin-top:     0;
        display:        table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
        position:       relative;
        top:            0px;
        left:           0px;
        padding-left:   0.4em;
        padding-right:  0.4em;
    }
    div#content_right {
        width:          768px;
        display:        table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-radius:  8px;
    }
    div.content_block_standard {
        width:              90%;
        margin-left:        auto;
        margin-right:       auto;
        padding:            1.0em;
    }

div.screenshots {
    text-align:         center;
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
    background:         linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.0),rgba(0,0,0,0.0),rgba(22,122,222,0.2));
    padding:            4px;
}

img.thumbnail {
    width:              128px;
    height:             auto;
}
```

Comment: You may need to provide the relevant (HTML, CSS, jQuery) code you are using, a screen shot of the issue and eventually, a jsfiddle where the problem can be reproduced, otherwise the question is too broad and faces the risk to be down-voted and/or closed without an answer.

Comment: Added the code I believe is relevant, as well as a jsfiddle link. My apologies for not having included anything originally. Lesson learned: Don't spend an hour right before bed getting frustrated at something, then post about it. ;)

Comment: FYI- you're including FancyBox twice in your jsFiddle.

Comment: @Sparky - Good point. Removed the bad one.

Comment: It seems the issue you have is because you missed to include the fancybox CSS file. Here the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ttvpg8vp/7/) with the fix.

Comment: @JFK - You are correct, sir. I discovered that about half an hour ago, wrote up an answer, and completely forgot to hit 'Submit'. I am ashamed at my ignorance - on multiple fronts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I *was* missing something obvious, I was *not* including all the relevant code for anyone to help me (newbie mistake), and was failing to pay attention to that little red X in Chrome's Element Inspector.

**I had the path to FancyBox's stylesheet wrong. That's was all it was.**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this is expected behaviour when an element is positioned 75% relative to the screen. Only on the other remaining 25% of the screen the element will be visible and the rest will be outside of the viewport.

Try this: (for this example I use an element width and height of 800px)

```
left: 50%; // position the left side of the box to be in the exact center
top: 50% // position the top of the box to be in the exact center
margin-left: -400px; // half of the width
margin-top:-400px; // half of the height
```

As you didn't provide us ANY code I'm not sure the solution above will work for you, but this is as far as it goes with centering absolute positioned elements to the parent element.

Cheers, Jeroen.

Comment: "...as though..."

I didn't position anything to intentionally make the FancyBox open and display like that. I'm saying that it looks like it was positioned that way (though I never positioned it).

As far as providing code goes, I'm not sure which parts you'd want. It's not a matter of copy and pasting the single page, as the page is built from a minimum of four different files. I've changed nothing in the firing of the FB code other than setting it to 'elastic'.

I'll double-check to see if there was something I missed (that I can spot), and look into jsfiddle (no idea what that is).